# Travis CI failed because cannot accept license Constrain Layout

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci, android-sdk-tools, android-constraintlayout

Before i write this question, i already search same question about this, they did export license because still use alpha version of constrain layout. But now android already release stable version of constrain layout. I tried a lot of setup but still failed..

my latest `.travis.yml`

```
language: android

jdk: oraclejdk8

android:
  components:
    - platform-tools
    - tools # to get the new `repository-11.xml`
    - tools # see https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6040#issuecomment-219367943)
    - build-tools-25.0.0
    - android-25

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository

  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'

script:
   - ./gradlew clean build
```

and this is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.my"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.3.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

with this setup i got this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.1, Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.1].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 1 mins 55.975 secs
The command "./gradlew clean build" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

is there any solution without workaround using export license ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Updated response

> is there any solution without workaround using export license?

Yes, you can use the new `sdkmanager` to [install the constraint library and accept the license](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/constraint-layout/jobs/220841506#L1601):

```
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.2"
```

Otherwise, the missing component will be detected by `gradle` and downloaded without accept it:

```
  # Show version and download Gradle Wrapper if it's not already cached
  - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${DIR} && ./gradlew --version
  # Clean project and download missing dependencies and components
  - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${DIR} && ./gradlew clean build
```

In that case, as explained below, you need to accept the license the first time via the workaround.

[Full working sample using constraint-layout codelab repository for Android API level 22 to 25:](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/constraint-layout/builds/220841505)

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
sudo: required # false for Container-Based Infrastructure, required for Sudo-enabled Infrastructure

before_cache:
  - rm -f ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock # Avoid to repack it due locks
  - rm -f ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/caches/3.3/classAnalysis/classAnalysis.lock
  - rm -f ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/caches/3.3/jarSnapshots/jarSnapshots.lock

cache:
  directories:
    - ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/caches/
    - ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/wrapper/dists/

notifications:
  email: false

android:
  components: # Cookbooks version: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/9c6cd11
    - tools # Update preinstalled tools from revision 24.0.2 to 24.4.1
    - build-tools-25.0.2 # Match build-tools version used in build.gradle
    - platform-tools # Update platform-tools to revision 25.0.3+
    - tools # Update tools from revision 24.4.1 to 25.2.5

env:
  global:
    - DIR=constraint-layout-start # Project directory
    - API=25 # Android API level 25 by default
    - TAG=google_apis # Google APIs by default, alternatively use default
    - ABI=armeabi-v7a # ARM ABI v7a by default
    - QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none # Disable emulator audio to avoid warning
    - GRADLE_USER_HOME="${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle" # Change location for Gradle Wrapper and cache
    - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-24.0.2 # Depends on the cookbooks version used in the VM
    - TOOLS=${ANDROID_HOME}/tools # PATH order matters, exists more than one emulator script
    - PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${TOOLS}:${TOOLS}/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=20 # minutes (2 minutes by default)

matrix:
  include: # More Emulator API levels to build in parallel
    - env: API=24
    - env: API=23
    - env: API=22
  allow_failures:
    - env: API=23
    - env: API=22
  fast_finish: false

before_install:
  - export EMULATOR="system-images;android-${API};${TAG};${ABI}" # Used to install/create emulator
  - echo 'count=0' > /home/travis/.android/repositories.cfg # Avoid warning

install:
  # List and delete unnecessary components to free space
  - sdkmanager --list || true
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "system-images;android-15;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "system-images;android-16;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "system-images;android-17;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "system-images;android-18;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "extras;google;google_play_services"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "extras;android;support"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-10"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-15"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-16"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-17"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-18"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-19"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-20"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-21"
  - sdkmanager --uninstall "build-tools;21.1.2"
  # Update sdk tools to latest version and install/update components
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "tools"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-25" # Latest platform required by SDK tools
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-${API}" # Android platform required by emulator
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.2"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "$EMULATOR" # Install emulator system image
  # Create and start emulator
  - echo no | avdmanager create avd -n acib -k "$EMULATOR" -f --abi "$ABI" --tag "$TAG"
  - emulator -avd acib -engine classic -no-window -camera-back none -camera-front none -verbose -qemu -m 512 &
  # Start adbd, wait for device connected and show android serial
  - adb wait-for-device get-serialno
  # Show version and download Gradle Wrapper if it's not already cached
  - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${DIR} && ./gradlew --version
  # Clean project and download missing dependencies and components
  - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${DIR} && ./gradlew clean build
  # Check components status
  - sdkmanager --list || true

before_script:
  # Wait for emulator fully-booted and disable animations
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
  - sleep 30
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
  # Run all device checks
  - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${DIR} && ./gradlew connectedCheck

after_script:
  # Show tests and lint results
  - cat ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${DIR}/*/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/*
  - cat ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${DIR}/*/build/reports/lint-results.xml
```

Two more samples using `sdkmanager` and `avdmanager` without `${DIR}` workaround:

- [Android Maps Utils library - Google](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/android-maps-utils/builds/220859379)
- [Dexter library - Karumi](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/Dexter/builds/220847349)

**References**

Official documentation related to [Auto-download missing packages with Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle)

The [new Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html) options are explained in [Start the Emulator from the Command Line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html)

`avdmanager` [explained here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html) replaces `android avd` since [SDK tools version 25.3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html)

`sdkmanager` [explained here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) also enhanced to view and accept all licenses from the command line

---

### Previous response: Since sdkmanager replaces android script

I'm a little outdated about Travis-ci and seems extra work is required now, so it's better you check:

- As tir38 [noticed](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6653), `android` [tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html) is no longer supported. Instead, use `sdkmanager`...
- Open [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212128) and [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144426/1009132) for this topic:

> In your `.travis.yml` file add:
>
> ```
> before_install:
>   - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
>   - echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
>   - echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
> ```
>
> Do not forgot to accept all the licences on the main `android` object:
>
> ```
> android:
>   components:
>     # ...
>   licenses:
>     - android-sdk-license-.+
>     - '.+'
> ```

- Another [related issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212128#c104) and workaround:

> If you are getting "Please install the missing components using the
>   SDK manager in Android Studio." error you can just install the missing
>   component with the sdkmanager command line tool:
>
> ```
> echo y | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-beta4"
> echo y | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-beta"
> ```

- [This article](https://medium.com/@oldergod/constraint-layout-and-circleci-travis-d50342696d2#.u98wf893w) explaining contraint-layout problem for Circle-ci and Travis-ci
- [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#usage) about sdkmanager  provided in the Android SDK Tools package (25.2.3+)

---

### Outdated solution: Before android script deprecation

I don't use the default Travis-ci script to install Android components and accept licenses, [from here](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/blob/acib/scripts/acib#L42):

```
# Install and update SDK
function install-and-update-sdk {
    # Keep SDK packages up-to-date (only missing suggested updates are installed).
    ( sleep 5 && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo y; done ) | android update sdk -u -t \
        ${UPDATE_PKGS:-'platform-tools,tools,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository'}
    # Install or reinstall SDK packages (if empty, all packages are installed).
    ( sleep 5 && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo y; done ) | android update sdk -a -u -t \
        ${INSTALL_PKGS:-'build-tools-23.0.3,android-23'},${TARGET_PKGS:-}
}
```

You can accept all the licenses at the same time if you do it like [this](https://github.com/ardock/iosched/blob/1f793d83ed995dbc72034e519f2c1bbd9fb13b81/.travis.yml#L365):

```
# THE SETUP STAGE
# ---------------
# If you comment out this section, Travis CI will install for you the components you define here.
# Check your project requirements and the components included by default on Travis-ci VM images.
# Check required: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/doc/BUILDING.md
# Check defaults: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/#Pre-installed-components

android:
  components:
    # Check Android SDK tools: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html
    # Check Android SDK Platform-tools: http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html
    # Comment the lines below if the latest revisions of Android SDK Tools are included by default.
    # - tools
    # - platform-tools
    # ...
  licenses:
    # Check licenses: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/#Dealing-with-Licenses
    # By default Travis will accept all the licenses, but it's also possible to define a white list:
    # White list current android-sdk-license revision.
    # - 'android-sdk-license-5be876d5'
    # White list all android-sdk-license revisions.
    # - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    # White list all the licenses.
    - '.+'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for update, i used your sample but i got this error `File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.` `google-services.json` is my api key, then i shouldn't put it on my repository

Comment: I didn't try it and it's out of scope, a quick google-fu shows these alternatives: [encrypt](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files) or [mock](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/pull/21). Further info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/error-file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google) and an open question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251441/commiting-google-services-json-to-github).

Comment: @martiendt check the awesome answer of the open question, perhaps it helps you.

Comment: Sample above is ridiculously helpful. Travis should really have these sample in their docs.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that worked for me was to copy the SDK licenses to my project from SDK and then tell Travis to copy them to itself while building.

There's already a closed issue for this on Travis's Github page and one of the mentioned solutions on it is definitely working currently.

**Solution**

1. Copy the `licenses` folder found in Android SDK's root directory.
2. Paste it in the root directory of your own project on the same hierarchy where `.travis.yml` file is.
3. Add these commands to your `.travis.yml`'s `before_install` block:

**.travis.yml**:

```
before_install:
- mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
- cp ./licenses/* "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/"
```

Exact link to solution: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6617#issuecomment-369580270

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I was using one old version of android build tools and gradle version, just updating them to the last version available did the trick.
For example, today the last version of gradle is 3.3, and build tools last version is 2.3.3. 
My build.gradle file looks like that

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```

This was raised as an issue some time ago https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37102998
and if you go to last answers you will se that the issue was fixed by just upgrading gradle version and build tools version.

Comment: link is not enough for answer, please add content here